# Make Ajax-call and take care of the response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use a free api in order to gather informationfrom the users Ip-adress.

This is the method:

```
public JsonResult GetIp()
        {

            string url = "http://ip-api.com/json";

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(url).GetDynamicJsonObject();

            return Json(googleResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The method is supposed to get called when the page is rendered so I am thinking something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetIp", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            //Here i need code that receives the Json from the controller...
        });
    });
```

Also, is this the best way to go about a task like this? I've been reading that Json could also be passed as a simple string? Any tips on best practice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be getting the client ip this way, you'll get the server ip, because that's the machine making the call.

What you want is to make that call directly, in javascript, so the request ip is the client's.

If you look at the response headers from that api, Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *, so you should be able to use that url directly.

And as Amin mentioned, just add a success method to handle the response, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://ip-api.com/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp){
            //resp.query
        }
    });
});
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BH5uR/)

Comment: Thank you! Not sure if I understand...If I paste:
http://ip-api.com/json
In my browser, I get all the info i need. I imagine that if you used my application,  the Json would contain values according to your position?

Comment: Exactly! Each user will get it's own data.

Comment: Aha..so i dont even need the method?
The problem seems to be that the method does not return anything back to the Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetIp", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(resp){
                //resp is the returned json variable from the server side
                //you can use it like "resp.id" or "resp.anyOtherValue"
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. However, this should mean that if I put: Alert(resp.Country) in the response. It would Alert it? 
I get an Alert: undefined. When I put a breakpoint at the return-value of the method it shows that I got the document there.

Comment: are you sure about the `.Country`? is it not miss-spelled or something? because it must be alerted if everything's fine on the server side!

Comment: Yes, i am sure, if you paste:
http://ip-api.com/json
In your browser you will get a Json containing for examle .country. Thanks

Comment: ok so it's `.country` with small "c", remember that variables are case sensitive! you must use it as `resp.country`